# Backbone.js once() event method: counter increment example

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am reading [Developing Backbone.js Applications](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/).

There's an example on `once()` method that I don't understand. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonkim/dR68U/1/). Run it and see the console log. See that it prints two `true`s.

```
var TodoCounter = { counterA: 0, counterB: 0 };
_.extend(TodoCounter, Backbone.Events);

// Increment counterA, triggering an event
var incrA = function(){ 
  TodoCounter.counterA += 1; 
  TodoCounter.trigger('event'); // ??? What is this for?
};

// Increment counterB
var incrB = function(){ 
  TodoCounter.counterB += 1; 
};

// Use once rather than having to explicitly unbind
// our event listener
TodoCounter.once('event', incrA);
TodoCounter.once('event', incrB); 

// Trigger the event once again
TodoCounter.trigger('event');

// Check out output
console.log(TodoCounter.counterA === 1); // true
console.log(TodoCounter.counterB === 1); // true
```

Does `TodoCounter.trigger('event')` in `incrA()` do anything? I removed it, and it didn't seem to make any difference.

The book says it only should increment once for A and B. I think I understand that except `TodoCounter.trigger('event')` in `incrA()`.

Comment: Developing Backbone.js Applications looks like one to add to the reading list, even if it does have somewhat confusing examples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are correct, it won't do anything. I believe its just making the point that the callback is only fired one time when `once()` is used to bind it to the event.

Comment: No problem. I suppose the counter example would be to use TodoCounter.on('event', incrA); instead and an infinite loop would be the result.